# How can I view only comments, functions and returns in a php file?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ide, aptana

**Clarification**:
I an using Aptana/Eclipse and would like to open any php file and generate an overview of existing code. So that I can quickly determine what the code attempts to do and how from a birds eye perspective.

I've tried to find an existing solution to no avail. I dont wish to program something as I would think that somehow this can be done using the right plugin or combo of native features built in to eclipse. The resulting outline I'm shooting for would include comments, functions and to a limited degree returns.

It would look something like the following:

```
/**
* This file creates an objet
*
* TODO: something
*/

//This function does something
function example();
  //first it does this
  //then it does this
  //then show any returns if applicable
  return function();

//This function does something else
function another_example();
  return 'whatever';
```

Other returns to include would be:

`return 'string';`

`return $variable;`

Not the whole array, it is sufficient to just know that it is an array.

`return array();`

`return TRUE;`

`return FALSE;`

`return NULL;`

Switch case returns like this:

```
switch  
  case 'a':
    return ...;
  case 'b':
    return ...;
return '-';
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at [PHP Documentor](http://www.phpdoc.org/), you will need to modify your comment structure a bit ([here is the spec](http://www.phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/index.html)), but it will generate great documentation from your code. [Example](http://demo.phpdoc.org/Clean/)

Answer (score 0):

You could also use something like [Docco](http://jashkenas.github.io/docco/)

It's run on node.js, but produces beautiful side by side documentation.